# stdout captured from command has twice as many newlines when passed to selenium

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess, newline

I have a bit of code that I am trying to capture the stdout:

```
def MediaInfo():
    cmd= ['MediaInfo.exe', 'videofile.mkv']
    test = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)
    info = test.stdout.decode("utf-8")
    print (info)
```

When using `print` or writing it to file, it looks fine. But when I use selenium to fill it into a message box:

```
techinfo = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "techinfo").send_keys(info)
```

there is an additional empty line between every line. Originally I had an issue where the `stdout` was a byte literal. It looked like `b"This is the first line.\r\nThis is the second line.\r\n"` Adding `.decode("utf-8")` is what fixed that but I am wondering if in certain instances something is interpreting `\r\n` as creating two lines. I'm just not sure if it is an issue with Selenium or subprocess or something else. The webpage element Selenium is writing to doesn't seem to have an issue. It looks correct if I copy and paste it from the text file. Meaning, it's not just the way it's displayed, there are actually twice as many line feeds. Any ideas? I don't want to just loop through and delete the extra lines. Too kludgy. I'm guessing this is an issue with Python 3, from what I've read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send_keys() will send each key individually which means "\r\n" is sent as two key presses. Replacing "\r\n" with "\n" prior to sending to element should do the trick.

Comment: I had an inkling it was something like that. I had actually tried that but I was getting an error and it wasn't working, didn't think much of it. I looked back after your comment and realized I made a mistake by adding the replace to the `test` part and not `info`, and again by adding it to the wrong section of code I failed to clean up. Changing it to `info = test.stdout.decode("utf-8").replace('\r\n', '\n')` fixed the issue. +1 for explaining the reason for why this was occurring. Thank you much.